# Plotting function with sums

Tags: matplotlib, julia

However I try to plot a function including a sum I get errors. Can´t find any example anywhere.

```
using PyPlot

x = range(0,stop=2,length=10)

f(x) = x + 1

plot(x,f(x))
```

for example gives me:

```
MethodError: no method matching +(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Int64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the plotting. The problem is that you try to add a number (`1`) to a range (`x`). This is also what the error message states. You need to do it element-wise. Like in e.g. matlab this is achieved with `.`-operations.

There are two possibilities for you in this example.

- either `f(x) = x .+ 1; plot(x,f(x))`
- or `f(x) = x + 1; plot(x,f.(x))`

Take a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1